# Watch_dogs crash on startup due to dual AMD GPUs

Tags: watch-dogs

I got Watch_dogs and when I opened it up it looked great, until the screen comes where it says that the game has an autosave feature, then it crashed (right after the ubisoft splashscreen)

Before the crash it seemed to run at 30-40 fps.

I then turned my weaker GPU of, and this seemed to fix the problem, the game doesn't crash, however it only runs at 5-10 fps (also doing the initial ubisoft splashscreen)

Is there a way to run Watch_Dogs with two AMD GPUs?

My GPUs are:

- AMD Radeon HD 7640G
- AMD Radeon HD 7700M

The stronger one should be able to run the game alone at 720, but it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: There could be some motherboard issues caused by cross-firing two different GPUs

Comment: Have you tried updating your drivers?

Comment: @badp yes, but it still didn't work ;(

Comment: @MechanicalBanana shouldn't that affect other games too? (i can still play games like sleeping dogs or red faction guerilla without a problem with both gpu's turned on)

Comment: What is the dedicated memory of the 7640G? Watch dogs minimum requirement is for 1024mb dedicated.

Comment: Also, what processor does your system have?

Comment: @TZHX The 7700M has 2GB dedikatet the processer is an A8 4500M however the problem seems to be with the gpu, since it doesn't lag but crahses or lags but loads